# How to tune the quality of festival TTS?

Tags: festival, text-to-speech

I am using 2.1 release of festival. I was able to install and use 172M voice with

```
(voice_cmu_us_slt_arctic_clunits)
```

The quality has been significantly improved but far from desired. I believe generation still uses a lot of defaults. Is it possible to tune this further (e.g. close to the quality of qwiki.com engine)? I understand that I need a proper combination of

- Synthesis method
- Intonation/duration settings
- Audio output parameters
- xx ?

but it is very difficult to find all the details (the progress is quite slow).

Any tips, links to [tutorials](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/emasters/summer_school_2005/tutorial3/tutorial.html)/[docs](http://festvox.org/docs/manual-1.4.3/festival_toc.html#TOC91) (old version but provides some theory overview) or scheme snippets are appreciated.

PS

Please note that so far I am not interested in the tuning of the algorithms themselves (e.g. training the voice model with *sphinx*).

To generate speech I use commands like

```
(SayText "This is a short introduction ...")
```

and

```
./text2wave -eval '(voice_cmu_us_slt_arctic_clunits)' TEXT > output.wav
```

Comment: trying nitech voices http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=751169&page=12

Comment: apparently this mini-howto is very informative http://leb.net/pub/blinux/doc/blinux/my-tts-linux.txt Every setting starting with *(Parameter.set ..* is of interest.